Codeception functional test on Symfony 7.0 error There is currently no session available
I am using Symfony 7.0 and Codeception for running various tests with the fallowing packages:
"require-dev": {              
    "codeception/codeception": "^5.1.2",
    "codeception/module-asserts": "^3.0",
    "codeception/module-doctrine": "^3.1",
    "codeception/module-doctrine2": "^3.0",
    "codeception/module-phpbrowser": "^3.0.1",
    "codeception/module-redis": "^3.1",
    "codeception/module-rest": "^3.3",
    "codeception/module-symfony": "3.1.1",
    "codeception/module-webdriver": "^4.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.5"
}

I have the fallowing test that calls a method from another class:
namespace App\Tests\Functional;
use App\Controller\ReportController;
use App\Entity\Attribution\Report;
use App\Entity\User;
use Codeception\Lib\ModuleContainer;

class ReportControllerCest{

    
    public function testAddAction(FunctionalTester $I, ModuleContainer $moduleContainer)
    {
        $controller = $I->grabService(ReportController::class);
        $I->assertInstanceOf(Controller::class, $controller);

        $I->seeInRepository(User::class, ['email' => 'test@test.com']);

        $user = $I->grabEntityFromRepository(User::class, [
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
        ]);

        $I->amLoggedInAs($user);

        $request = new Request();
        $em = $moduleContainer->getModule('Doctrine')->_getEntityManager();

        $controller->newReport($em, $request, 'conversion_testing');
}


class ReportController extends AnotherController
{
................

#[Route(path: '/report/new', name: 'attribution_report_new')]
public function newReport(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, string $reportDefinitionTable)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();//codeception_debug($user) //everything ok here

    if($user->getAccountType() != "admin") {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Access not allowed!');
    }

    $report = new Report();
    $form = $this->createForm(AttributionReportType::class, $report);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
 
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        .......           
    }

    return $this->render('report/form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(            
        ]);
}
..............

App\\Tests.Functional Tests (1) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: Asserts, Symfony, Doctrine, Redis
-

ReportControllerCest: Test add action
Signature: App\\Tests\\Functional\\ReportControllerCest:testAddAction
Test: tests/Functional/ReportControllerCest.php:testAddAction
Scenario --
\[Symfony\] Can't set persistent service doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager: The "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service is already initialized, you cannot replace it.
\[Database\] Transaction started
I grab service "App\\Controller\\ReportController"
I assert instance of "App\\Controller\\ReportController","App\\Controller\\ReportController"
I see in repository "App\\Entity\\User",{"email":"test@test.com"}
SELECT s FROM App\\Entity\\User s WHERE s.email = ?0
I grab entity from repository "App\\Entity\\User",{"email":"test@test.com"}
SELECT s FROM App\\Entity\\User s WHERE s.email = ?0
I am logged in as "App\\Entity\\User"
ERROR

\[Database\] Transaction cancelled; all changes reverted.
-

Time: 00:04.645, Memory: 66.50 MB

There was 1 error:

1) AtrributionReportControllerCest: Test add action
   Test  tests/Functional/AtrributionReportControllerCest.php:testAddAction

\[Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Exception\\SessionNotFoundException\] There is currently no session available.

There was an update from Symfony 5.4 to Symfony 7.0 and didn't had this problem before the update. When accessing the route /report/new from the web interface everything works as expected.
Did anyone encountered this Session issue on Symfony when running functional tests?
